# Trigger timer prematurely

Tags: go, timer

I have a loop that is sleeping for some period of time. However, elsewhere in my code I might need to end that sleep time prematurely so that the succeeding logic can be executed sooner.

```
for {
    timer = time.NewTimer(30 * time.Second)
    <-timer.C
    // Do something
}
```

Elsewhere…

```
// Trigger timer
// timer.Trigger() ??
```

Naturally, `timer.Stop()` will stop the timer, but it will then cause the program to hang and not drop down to `// Do something`. Currently, I am resetting the timer to a very small duration so that the timer will expire basically immediately.

```
timer.Reset(time.Millisecond)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a cancellation channel:

```
cancel := make(chan struct{})
for {
    timer = time.NewTimer(30 * time.Second)
    select {
    case <- timer.C:
        doSomething()
    case <- cancel:
        doSomething()
    }
}
```

When you want to ignore the timer and execute immediately, just send a message on the `cancel` channel:

```
cancel <- struct{}{}
```